# Como saber de qual activity anterior a activity atual foi chamada?

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho varias Activities, que podem chamar uma Activity especial.

Gostaria de saber como identificar qual foi a activity que chamou.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso disso pq tenho uma activity de registro de usuário, que pode ser chamada através de vários lugares na minha aplicação. Mas eu preciso saber de qual lugar ele foi chamado, pq dependendo de quem chamou ele deve executar uma ação.

Eu Pensei em fazer assim:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(basecontext,Registro_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("ACTIVITYPAI", "ACTIVITY-A");
startActivity(intent);
```

E colocar isso em cada tela que for chamar. Mas se tiver um modo de não precisar usar o putExtra, e a própria activity de registro identificar de onde ela veio, seria melhor pra mim.

Comment: Acredito usar o putExtra seja menos custoso para este caso. A não ser que você tenha um motivo muito especial para descartar esta solução.

Comment: @Viana O meu motivo para tentar evitar, é que não sei ainda quantas activities vão chamar esta mesma activity, penso que seria mais prático pra mim, saber de onde vem e fazer a verificação apenas no que eu precisar. Assim se um dia eu resolver mudar tudo isto, eu mudarei apenas na activity que está sendo chamada, e não precisarei modificar todas as outras que chamam por ela. Entende?? Não sei se expliquei direito kkk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Utilizando getCallingActivity():

Se você iniciar a Activity com `startActivityForResult`, é possível utilizar o método `getCallingActivity().getClassName()`:

```
private void startRegistroActivity() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(basecontext, Registro_Activity.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}
```

E na segunda activity:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ...
  String className = getCallingActivity().getClassName();

}
```

### Utilizando Intents:

É possível também utilizar Intents, como você já está fazendo.

Na primeira `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(basecontext,Registro_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("activity_name", this.getClass().getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

E na segunda `Activity`:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ...
  String className = getIntent().getStringExtra("activity_name");
}
```

### Utilizando Singletons ou objetos que vivem mais que a Activity:

Outra opção é utilizar objetos que vivem mais que a Activity, como Singletons.

Declare o Singleton:

```
public enum ActivityReference {

  INSTANCE;

  Class<?> callingActivity;

  public Class<?> getCallingActivity() {
    return callingActivity;
  }

  public void setCallingActivity(Class<?> callingActivity) {
    this.callingActivity = callingActivity;
  }
}
```

Guarde o valor nele:

```
ActivityReference.INSTANCE.setCallingActivity(this.getClass());
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

A acesse posteriormente:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ...
  Class<?> callingActivity = ActivityReference.INSTANCE.getCallingActivity();
}
```

Comment: Poderia me dizer como eu poderia fazer através de Singletons?? `startActivityForResult` talvez funcione para mim. Vou tentar deste modo que você sugeriu, mas gostaria de saber como seria com singleton também, se puder me dar um exemplo.

Comment: @SamantaSilva adicionei exemplos na resposta

Comment: Obrigadaaa, ainda não testei pra saber qual dos métodos vai ser o melhor pra mim, mas adorei a resposta.